# Hitting times by Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stopping-times

[Edited] Suppose that $A$ is a (Borel) measurable set and $X$ is an Ito diffusion, i.e., $dX_{t}=\mu(X_t)dt+\sigma(X_t)dB_t$.

Consider a hitting time $\tau_A$ of the given set $A$ by the process $X$: $\tau_A:=\inf\{t\geq0:X_t\in A\}$.

Also, let $\tau_\bar{A}:=\inf\{t\geq0:X_t\in \bar{A}\}$ where $\bar{A}$ is the closure of $A$.

Now, my question is: Is $\tau_\bar{A} = \tau_A$ (a.s.)? I think this must be true, but I do not find any reference for this... In case my conjecture is incorrect, any idea on reasonable conditions (either on $A$ or $X$) under which this is true?

I'd really appreciate your help!

---

Based on the comments below, suppose that $X_t$ is an Ito diffusion process and let me refine my question as follows:

1. Let $X_0 = x$. If the process $X$ comes back to $x$ infinitely often in any time interval $(0,\epsilon)$, $\epsilon>0$, then can we say that my assertion above ($\tau_\bar{A} = \tau_A$ (a.s.)) is true? My intuition is that if $X$ has this property, then along with the Markov property of $X$, for any given $t$, a sample path $X_{s>t}$ always "zig-zagged" around $X_t$ for any $s>t$. So, given any set $A$, as soon as $X$ hits its boundary point of $A$ (which belongs to the closure of $A$), it should also hit $A$ in arbitrarily small time $\epsilon>0$. Does my argument make sense?
2. If #1 is correct, then the follow-up question is: under what condition on $\mu(\cdot)$ and $\sigma(\cdot)$ an Ito diffusion $X$ has this property? As a canonical example, does a Brownian motion with drift ($\mu(\cdot)=\mu$ and $\sigma(\cdot)=\sigma$) have this property?

Any idea or suggestion for the reference would be really appreciated!

Comment: Maybe useful: For a standard Brownian motion starting at $0$, it has [infinitely many zeros in any interval $(0,\epsilon)$](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2010/REUPapers/Dahl.pdf) and particular is both positive and negative infinitely often.

Comment: For Brownian motion itself you can try to argue as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3102206/36150) ... I rather doubt that the assertion is true for general Itô processes. (It's somewhat confusing that you call $X$ a "Brownian motion with drift" ... your $X$ is actually an Itô process. A Brownian motion with drift is a process of the form $X_t = \mu t + \sigma B_t$, i.e. $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are just constants.)

Comment: @eepperly16 Thank you so much for your help! Yes it was indeed very helpful and I've got some clues thanks to you!

Comment: @saz Thank you for your answer! I added some thoughts to the original post based on your idea. Could you please take a look at it and let me know what you think? Thank you!

Comment: @saz if we would know that the stopping times are finite a.s., couldn't we conclude the assertion through the strong Markov property of Ito diffusions?

Comment: @Shashi Why do you think so? I wouldn't expect it (e.g. because of the counterexample from your question). In case of Brownian motions the reasoning works because we know that it wiggles around at $t=0$ but in general it's not that simple.

Comment: @saz but in the counterexample we see that one of the stopping times is infinite, so...

Comment: Sure, but the smaller one is finite, i.e. you could use strong Markov property to condition on $\tau_A^-$ ... just that it doesn't give you anything useful. But, well, perhaps you are right; I'm just saying that I wouldn't expect it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I'm very new in this field, but I'm giving a try anyways. So please be critical and let me know if something is wrong (We are here to learn so...).*

The assertion is not true in general, indeed we have a couple of counterexamples.

**A simple counterexample.**
Let $\mu\equiv 1$ and $\sigma\equiv 0$. Define
$$A:=(0,1)$$
Then we have for $X_0=1$, the explicit unique solution for $X_t$ given by
$$X_t=1+t$$
In this particular case $$\tau_A=\infty, \ \ \text{ and }\ \ \ \tau_A^-=0.$$

---

We might add extra conditions to get that $\tau_A=\tau_A^-$ a.s., I guess we can cook up the following simple proposition which is inspired by Saz' comment. I also add some thoughts at the end. But before we do that we need some Lemmas. Let us fix the filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathcal F_t,\mathbb P)$.

> **Lemma 1.** For the case $X=B$ we have
>   $$\tau_A=\tau_A^- \ \ \ \text{ a.s. }$$

*Proof.* This Lemma is a generalization of what Saz proved here in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3102206/349501). The proof should go more or less the same so it will be omitted.

///

Now we say the same if we consider time-changed Brownian motions.

> **Lemma 2.** Let $(T(t))_{t\geq 0}$ be a strictly increasing and continuous stochastic process such that $T(0)=0$ and $\lim_{t\to\infty}T(t)=\infty$. Then for $X_t=B_{T(t)}$ we have
>   $$\tau_A=\tau_A^- \ \ \ \text{ a.s. }$$

*Proof.* Since $t\mapsto T(t)(\omega)$ for some fixed $\omega\in\Omega$ is increasing and continuous we have the existence of increasing and continuous "inverse random variable" $t\mapsto T^{-1}(t)(\omega)$. The domain of $T$ and $T^{-1}$ (as a function of $t$) is $[0,\infty)$. We have
\begin{align}
\tau_A&=\inf\{t\geq 0 \ :\ B_{T(t)}\in A\}\\
&=\inf\{t\geq 0\ : \ s=T(t), \ B_s\in A\}\\
&=T^{-1}(\inf\{s\geq 0\ : \ B_s\in A\}) \\
&=T^{-1}(\inf\{s\geq 0\ : \ B_s\in \overline{A}\}) \\
&=...\\
&=\tau_A^{-1}
\end{align}
In the third line we have used continuity and monotonicity of $T^{-1}$ and the line before the dots is due to Lemma 1. In the dots we did the steps above with $\overline{A}$ to get the last line.

///

Now we can finally state the proposition.

> **Proposition.** Assume that $\mu$ and $\sigma$  are Lipschitz continuous so that a unique solution $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ exists for $X_0=x\in\mathbb R$. Moreover assume that $\sigma$ is bounded away from zero, i.e. there is $c>0$ such that $|\sigma|\geq c$. Finally assume that
>   $$Z_t=\exp\left(-\int^t_0 \frac{\mu(X_s)}{\sigma(X_s)}\,dB_s+\frac 1 2 \int^t_0\frac{\mu(X_s)^2}{\sigma(X_s)^2}\,ds \right)$$
>   is a $\mathcal F_t$-martingale. Then we have that $\tau_A=\tau_A^-$ a.s..

*Proof.* Sinze $Z_t$ is a martingale, we can define a probability measure $\mathbb Q$, that is equivalent to $\mathbb P$, by
$$\frac{d\mathbb Q}{d\mathbb P}|_{\mathcal F_t}=Z_t$$
Applying Girsanov gives us that
$$W_t=B_t+\int^t_0\frac{\mu(X_s)}{\sigma(X_s)}\,ds$$
is a BM w.r.t. $\mathbb Q$. We also verify w.r.t. $\mathbb Q$ we can write $X$ as 
$$X_t=x+\int^t_0\sigma(X_s) \,dW_s$$
Now we notice that 
$$\langle X\rangle_t=\int^t_0 \sigma(X_s)^2\,ds\geq \int^t_0 c^2\,ds=tc^2$$
Therefore $\langle X\rangle_\infty=\infty$. By the [Theorem of Dubins-Schwarz](https://eventuallyalmosteverywhere.wordpress.com/2012/05/27/dubins-schwarz-theorem/), there exists a BM w.r.t. $\mathbb Q$, say $\tilde W$, such that
$$X_t=x+\tilde W_{\langle X\rangle_t}$$
Now take $T(t)=\langle X\rangle_t$. Apply Lemma 2 with this $T(t)$ and $A'=A-\{x\}$ to get the proof done.

---

**Some remarks/thoughts.**

- The proposition shows that, in particular, a BM with drift satisfies the property.
- There are lot of ways to show that $Z_t$ is a martingale, maybe Novikov's or Kazamaki are applicable.
- Thanks to Saz who told me to use Dubins-Schwarz Theorem to mke the proposition applicable to a larger class of Ito-diffusions.

Comment: Didn't check all the details of your answer but I totally agree that the drift component can be discussed away using Girsanov's theorem provided that $\sigma$ is constant. For non-constant $\sigma$ you could try to use that any (nice) continuous martingale $M$ can be written in the form $M_t = B_{\langle M \rangle_t}$ where $B$ is a Brownian motion

Comment: @saz Right! That theorem is nice! I will try to write a modified version later when I have time. Please do not hesitate to write one answer yourself, you do it much better than I would do!

Comment: @Shashi Wow thank you so much for your answer! Yes for my claim to be true, we have to make sure that the process $X$ is not "stuck" somewhere, so I think it's necessary to assume that $\sigma(X)$ is bounded away from zero.

Comment: @Shashi By the way, in your argument, why did you need to make sure that $\tau_A<\infty$?

Comment: @saz answer updated. What do you think?

Comment: @ykdec answer updated. Now we have  larger class. We need $\tau_A<\infty$ a.s. because we need to apply the Strong Markov property in the proof of the answer of Saz' in the other post. With the new assumptions, we get automatically that $\tau_A<\infty$ as well. What do you think?

Comment: @Shashi Looks quite nice!

Comment: @Shashi Thank you so much for your update! Although I still don't see the need for $\tau_A < \infty$ almost surely, I think your proof works.