How can I show that as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ $\inf\{t\geq 0: B_t\geq 1+\epsilon\}\rightarrow \inf\{t\geq 0:B_t\geq 1\}$ almost surely?

Let $B$ be a a real valued Brownian motion starting from $0$ and $\epsilon >0$. I want to show that as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ then $\inf\{t\geq 0: B_t\geq 1+\epsilon\}\rightarrow \inf\{t\geq 0:B_t\geq 1\}$ almost surely.

Let me define $T_a=\inf\{t\geq 0:B_t\geq a\}$. My problem is that intuitively it make sense since $B$ has continuous sample paths and hence $T_{1+\epsilon}>T_1$ and thus as epsilon converges to zero we first also this stopping times should converge. But I don't know how to prove this rigorously. I thought about using the strong Markov property at $T_1$ since $T_1<T_{1+\epsilon}$ but I also don't know what this helps.
I have the following version of the strong Markov property:
Let $\tau$ be a stopping time and $\Phi$ a measurable bounded or non-negative function. Then,
\begin{align}
    \mathbb{E}\left(1_{\tau<\infty} \Phi\left(\left(B_{\tau+t}\right)_{t\geq 0}\right)|\mathcal{F}_\tau\right)=1_{\tau<\infty} \mathbb{E}_{B_\tau}\left(\Phi\left((B_t)_{t\geq 0}\right)\right).
\end{align}
Can someone help me?

The continuity question of hitting time $\tau_{a}:=\inf\{t\geq 0: B_{t}\geq a\}$ is an interesting and deep discussion.
First of all, we don't have right-continuity. As mentioned here Drawdown Point Processes and in the notes on stable subordinators, we only have: left-continuity with right-limits. So one often considers the continuous modification $\tau_{a^{+}}:=\lim_{t\downarrow a}\tau(t)$ to get right-continuity. The lack of right-continuity can also be seen from the filtration not being right-continuous e.g. see here Hitting time of an open set is not a stopping time for Brownian Motion.
In Drawdown Point Processes, he studies the difference $\tau_{a^{+}}-\tau_{a}>0$ and obtains a Poisson point process describing their difference. In particular as mentioned here pg.9 Subordinators, we have that
$$\tau_{a}=\int_{0}^{\infty}x\Pi_{a}(dx),$$
where $\Pi_{a}$ is a Poisson point process with intensity
$$dt\times \rho(dx)=dt\times \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}x^{-3/2}dx.$$
However, we do have convergence in probability i.e. from pg.9 Subordinators
$$P(\tau_{a+\epsilon}-\tau_{a}\geq q)=\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{q}^{\infty}x^{-3/2}e^{-\epsilon^{2}/(2x)}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{q/\epsilon^{2}}^{\infty}x^{-3/2}e^{-1/(2x)}dx\to 0\text{ as }\epsilon\to 0.$$
This also implies convergence almost surely since by continuity of measure we have
$$P(\lim_{\epsilon_{0}\to 0}\sup_{\epsilon\leq \epsilon_{0}}\tau_{a+\epsilon}-\tau_{a}\geq q)
=\lim_{\epsilon_{0}\to 0}P(\tau_{a+\epsilon_{0}}-\tau_{a}\geq q).$$
And yes as you mention (and LeGall mentions in Lemma 7.21 in his textbook "Brownian Motion, Martingales, and Stochastic Calculus"), an easier way to see this is instead to just use the strong Markov property
$$\tau_{a+\epsilon_{0}}-\tau_{a}=\tau_{\epsilon_{0}}\circ \tau_{a}\stackrel{dis}{=}\tilde{\tau}_{\epsilon_{0}},$$
where now the Brownian motion $\tilde{B}$ again starts from $0$. So as he recommends we use Proposition 2.14(i) that when $q>0$
$$\sup_{0\leq s\leq q}\tilde{B}_{s}>0\text{ a.s. }$$
to get
$$P_{0}(\tau_{a+\epsilon_{0}}-\tau_{a}\geq q)=P_{0}(\tau_{\epsilon_{0}}\geq q)=P_{0}(\epsilon_{0}\geq \sup_{0\leq s\leq q}\tilde{B}_{s}>0)$$
and finally take limit $\epsilon_{0}\to 0$ to get zero
$$P(\lim_{\epsilon_{0}\to 0}\sup_{\epsilon\leq \epsilon_{0}}\tau_{a+\epsilon}-\tau_{a}\geq q)=\lim_{\epsilon_{0}\to 0}P_{0}(\epsilon_{0}\geq \sup_{0\leq s\leq q}\tilde{B}_{s}>0)=P_{0}(0\geq \sup_{0\leq s\leq q}\tilde{B}_{s}>0)=0.$$

Thanks for your answer, but is it really so complicated? Because in Le Gall they wrote that $T_{1+\epsilon}\downarrow T_1$ a.s. as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ is a consequence from the strong markov property at time $T_1$ and the fact that for any $\delta>0$, $\sup_{0\leq t\leq \delta}B_t>0$ and $\inf_{0\leq t\leq \delta}B_t<0$. Can you maybe also help me how to prove it in this way?

@user123234 yes, I added the details for the hint from LeGall.

Why can you interchange the limit and the probability in the last line?

By dominated convergence theorem applied to the indicator functions 1_{epsilon> sup B}.

Thank a lot, I mean in LeGall, he used $\inf{t\geq 0: B_t=a}$ can I say that since I have shown it for $T_a=\inf{t\geq 0: B_t\geq a}$ it also holds for $\inf{t\geq 0: B_t=a}$ since $\inf{t\geq 0: B_t\geq a}=\inf{t\geq 0: B_t=a}$?

Yes due to BM continuity.

Okey thanks so I can replace every $T_a$ by $T_a^+:=\inf{t\geq 0: B_t=a}$ in the proof and everything works i.e. every inequality is still correct? And the second question is, shouldnt $\Phi(\omega)$ from the answer below not be $\Phi(\omega)=1_{\phi(\omega)\geq \delta}$ instead of $1_{\phi(\omega)>\delta}$?

see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3102124/expressing-mathbbp-left-sup-s-leq-t-b-sa-right-in-terms-of-stoppin?noredirect=1&lq=1

Sorry I don't get what you want to tell me with that so yes I can replace it and the proof still works?

Yes. read the answer.

Thanks a lot. I would have another question about a proof in LeGall and wanted to ask if I could write you an email because explaining it here would become a bit difficult if someone don't know LeGall and then I think my question would get closed. I found your mail on your website, would this be okey for you?

So its about a step in one proof which I wanted to understand in detail, I think I have an argument but I would like to know if this works. If it is better for you that I ask it on MSE as a question I can do it, maybe you could take a look at it.

It's better to ask on MSE because others can help if I am busy.

Okey thank you, I asked something now, maybe you could take a look?

Define $\phi(\omega):=\inf\{t\ge 0:\omega_t-\omega_0\ge\varepsilon\}$, so
\begin{align}
 \phi\Bigl((B_{T_1+t})_{t\ge0}\Bigr)&=\inf\Bigl\{t\ge 0:B_{T_1+t}-B_{T_1}\ge\varepsilon\Bigr\}\\[.4em]
&=\inf\Bigl\{t\ge T_1:B_t\ge1+\varepsilon\Bigr\}-T_1\\[.4em]
&=T_{1+\varepsilon}-T_1.
\end{align}
Then, with $\tau:=T_1$ and $\Phi(\omega):=1_{\phi(\omega)>\delta}$, the strong Markov property you gave
$$
    \mathbb{E}\Bigl[1_{T_1<\infty} \Phi\bigl((B_{T_1+t})_{t\geq 0}\bigr)\:\Big|\:\mathcal{F}_{T_1}\Bigr]=1_{T_1<\infty}\,\mathbb{E}_{B_{T_1}}\Phi\bigl((B_t)_{t\geq 0}\bigr)
$$
translates into (I am removing the $\Bbb 1_{\{T_1<\infty\}}$ since $\Bbb P(T_1<\infty)=1$) :
\begin{align}
\text{a.s},\qquad\Bbb P\Bigl(T_{1+\varepsilon}-T_1>\delta\:\Big|\:\mathcal F_{T_1}\Bigr)&=\Bbb E_1\Phi\bigl((B_t)_{t\geq 0}\bigr)\\[.4em]
&=\Bbb P_1\Bigl(\inf\{t\ge0:B_t-1\ge\varepsilon\}>\delta\Bigr)\\[.4em]
&=\Bbb P\Bigl(\inf\{t\ge0:B_t\ge\varepsilon\}>\delta\Bigr)\\[.4em]
&=\Bbb P\Bigl(T_\varepsilon>\delta\Bigr)
\end{align}
(the third equality just comes from the invariance by translation of $B$). Taking expectation, it follows that $$\Bbb P(T_{1+\varepsilon}-T_1\ge\delta)=\Bbb P(T_\varepsilon\ge\delta).$$
You should be able to conclude from here that $T_{1+\varepsilon}-T_1\to0$ in probabilty as $\varepsilon\to0$ (and therefore also almost surely by a monotonicity argument).

You mean that since $T_\epsilon$ is monotonly decreasing as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ we have $$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \mathbb{P}(T_\epsilon \geq \delta)=\mathbb{P}(\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}T_\epsilon \geq \delta)=\mathbb{P}(0\geq \delta)=0$$

I meant, more simply, if a monotonic sequence $(X_n)_{n\ge0}$ converges in probability to $X$, then it also converges almost surely to $X$.

But convergence in probability does not imply a.s. convergence

Please read carefully. It does, if the sequence is monotonic (non-decreasing or non-increasing).
