# Calculate Probability of Bachier model hitting upper barrier

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stopping-times

Let $B_t$ be a standard brownian motion and $\mu, \sigma \in \mathbb{R}$ with $\sigma \neq 0$. Now let $X_t = \sigma B_t + \mu t$ be the Bachier model with votality $\sigma$ and drift $\mu$. Further let $a,b > 0$ and define the stopping time $\tau = \text{inf} \{t \geq 0 : X_t = a$ or $X_t = -b\}$.
As part of an exercise I need to prove that:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(X_\tau=a) = \frac{\text{exp}(-\frac{2\mu}{{\sigma}^2})-1}{\text{exp}(-\frac{2\mu}{{\sigma}^2}(a+b))-1}
\end{equation}
I am not sure how to tackle this problem. We did prove in our lecture that if we define the function $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ as:
\begin{equation}
g(x) = \frac{\text{exp}(-\frac{2\mu }{{\sigma}^2}x)-\text{exp}(\frac{2\mu }{{\sigma}^2}b)}{\text{exp}(-\frac{2\mu}{{\sigma}^2}a)-\text{exp}(\frac{2\mu }{{\sigma}^2}b)}
\end{equation}
then $g(X_t)$ is a martingale satisfying $g(a) = 1$ and $g(-b) = 0$, but I don't see how this helps. All this tells me is
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(X_\tau=a) = \mathbb{P}(g(X_{\tau})=1)
\end{equation}
Any help or hints would be appreciated.

Comment: after reading through [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3648907/use-the-martingale-m-t-exp-theta-b-t-%e2%88%92-theta2t-2-theta-in-mathbbr?rq=1) I believe there is an error in the exercise. I bleieve it should be: \begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(X_\tau=a) = \frac{\text{exp}(-\frac{2\mu}{{\sigma}^2}b)-1}{\text{exp}(-\frac{2\mu}{{\sigma}^2}(a+b))-1}
\end{equation} Not sure if this is correct now.

Answer (score 1):

As you note, $g(X_t)$ is a martingale; therefore (and more useful) the stopped process $Y_t:=g(X_{t\wedge \tau})$ is a *bounded* martingale, with $Y_0=g(0)$. Therefore
$$
g(0)=E[Y_0] = E[Y_\tau]= g(a)P[X_\tau = a]+g(-b)P[X_\tau=-b].
$$
(This requires the previously garnered knowledge (or the stipulation) that $P[\tau<\infty] = 1$.)